# how can I do lock in hbase now?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Rowlock function is not allow anymore.

```
htable.lockrow() is not provided in library
```

How can I implement lock in hbase?

Is there any method to help me do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client-side rowlocks are not supported now:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7315

Comment: how to implement server side lock, I'm new to hbase but I want to try.
Howerver, I don't know how to find proper article about this. Please help me.

Comment: If you read the comment on that JIRA. HBase team considered client side rowlocks as BAD IDEA. So, dont do it.
FYI, HBase provides atomicity at row level. So, why do you want to implement rowlocks?

Comment: thank you for you answer.
I will search atomicity of hbase by now!